# Kohana 3: Using a custom controller

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

In KO2, I had a file called libraries/CUSTOM_Controller.php, in which I kept common methods that I wanted to be available to all controllers.

Is there a similar way to do this in KO3? I don't see anything in the docs (such as they are) about overriding the controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here comes the philosophy of Kohana 3. If you look in this `SYSPATH/classes/controller.php` file you'll see that there is defined empty class wich extends `Kohana_Controller` class. That means you can overwrite `Controller` class.
Make your own Controller class located `APPPATH/classes/controller.php` (kohana will always search file in `APPPATH` first).

```
class Controller extends Kohana_Controller {
  public function myMethod(){
    // ...
  }
}
```

`$this->myMethod()` will be available in all your controllers and nothing from Kohanas core will be lost.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  One question though - is there any way to do this via the app folder, since I use my sys folder for multiple apps, and may need different methods available in different apps?

Comment: You should never modify system files, the extension should be added to the `application/classes/` folder.

Comment: I like this feature! Controller is extended by default.